# Is the open ball path-connected in metric space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose in metric space $X$, B(x) is an open ball around $x$, is it path-connected or connected?

---

In normed space, it is obviously true, but I don't know if it is true in general?

Answer (score 1):

On any set $X$, the discrete metric
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $x = y$,}\\
1 &\text{if $x\ne y$}\\
\end{cases}$$
defines the discrete topology, and if $X$ is not a singleton, then for any $x\in X$ the open ball $B(x,2) = X$ is neither connected nor path-connected.

Answer (score 0):

No. $\Bbb Q$ is a metric space (with standard metric).
Regarding your "obviously true": $\Bbb Q$ is also a normed vector space over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I think his notion of normed space is over the reals, in which case the open ball is a star-shaped set, which explains the "obvious" part.